# Поведение таблиц при выборке из табличных функций

Tags: sql-server

Объесните как происходит действия с реальными таблицами, если делать выборку с JOIN между табличными функциями, например

```
SELECT t2.* FROM TF_MyFunc(1,DEFAULT) LEFT OUTER JOIN  TF_MyFunc(1,3) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Cама функция `TF_MyFunc` выбирает данные из большого объёма данных по какойто логики исходя из параметров.
я предпологаю что функции заполняют временны таблицы а потом между ними делается связь, или ни так? если ни так тогда стоит создавать временые таблицы загонять данные туду а потом делать связь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаются временные таблицы в базе tempdb. Зачем делать это самому?

Comment: я просто не знал что они там создаются вот решил уточнить думал что нет, ну раз создаются то тогда нечего беспокоится... спасибо